# random forest importance - different %IncMSE on plot and in the data frame

Tags: r, random-forest

I need some help understanding the importance feature built in random forest package available for R.

After running random forest (rf), importance can be accessed with rf$importance. The data frame that is then returned contains two fields: %IncMSE and IncNodePurity.

Both of them can be plotted using varImpPlot() function that is built in random forest package. However, the %IncMSE values that are plotted do not correspond to the results accessed with the method mentioned previously (rf$importance).

Let me explain the problem on an example:

```
data(mtcars)
rf<-randomForest(mpg~ .,data=mtcars,importance=T,mtry=3)
rf$importance
varImpPlot(rf)
```

The maximum %IncMSE value is 9.91 (disp), but on the plot the maximum value is around 14. All other values on the plot and accessed with rf$importance also differ. (Notice that there are no differences in IncNodePurity)

Can somebody explain this? Which values are correct?

Comment: Note that there is also a component of the model object called `importanceSD`. It's plotting scaled values...and indeed there is a `scale` argument to `varImpPlot`.

Comment: @joran: You should post as an answer. If people want to deliver negative feedback because the questioner _should_ have read the help page and _should_ have defined a standard of "correctness" to be applied, they can still do so, but your comment seems a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 3):

As I noted in my comment, the reason they are not the same is because `varImpPlot` is plotting scaled values using the `importanceSD` component of the random forest object. This can be controlled using the `scale` argument to `varImpPlot`.